# IE11 and CORS working for some but not for others

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, cors

There are a lot of questions about this subject here and in other places, and I have been reading up on P3P, IE settings, XDocumentRequest and all things related the last few days, but I just can't seem to solve this problem.

I make a request from my domain to an api on another domain. The real url's and tokens are replaced with dummies for this example.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.myapiurl.com/companies/mycompany', // Third party
  type: 'get',
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'MYAUTHTOKEN123'
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
    if (data) {
      callback(data);
    }
  },
  error: function () {
    callback({
      'error': true
    });
  }
});
```

Should be said that my domain is `http` and the api is `https`, if that is relevant.

Here is the raw request from Fiddler

```
GET https://api.myapiurl.com/companies/mycompany HTTP/1.1
Authorization: MYAUTHTOKEN123
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Referer: http://review.mysiteurl.se/?c=mycompany
Accept-Language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.5
Origin: http://review.mysiteurl.se
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: api.myapiurl.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

And the raw response from my working environment

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://review.mysiteurl.se
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 04 Dec 2015 09:05:05 GMT
Server: undertow
Content-Length: 1001
Connection: keep-alive

{"name":"Mycompany","slug":"mycompany"}
```

Now this works great for me in IE11 on my local computer. It also works from [browserstack.com](https://www.browserstack.com) with the exact same setup as my customers. I have also tried from a few different remote locations, but it always works.

The last week I have been sending this link to my customers and a lot of them won't get past this and `$.ajax` goes to `error:` instead of `success:`.

I have asked them for as much information as possible, like this

```
Operating System: Windows Windows 7
Screen Resolution: 1920 x 1200
Web Browser: Internet Explorer 11.0
Browser Size: 1920 x 1084
IP Address: x.x.x.x
Color Depth: 16
Javascript: Enabled
Flash Version: 19.0.-1
Cookies: Enabled
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

Sadly I have had a hard time finding someone with some basic debugging skills to give me actual console outputs or javascript errors.

Tried to replicate that exact environment, but it still works perfect for me.

Now is there anything, like firewalls or some IE settings that might be commonly set as part of company policies that can cause this? I just don't know what to look at next when I just can't seem to replicate the problem. If it was one or two people I would blame it on some obscure setting and move on, but this is something like 20-30% of the users at 7 different companies.

Comment: Did you try logging `textStatus` and `errorThrown` in your error handler?

Comment: As for settings, IE/Internet Options has a lot of rather obscure settings that could influence this. I’d suggest you first of all try out the different default security levels for the relevant zone on your machine, and see if that makes the problem reproducible in one of them.

Comment: I will put a logger in for error thrown and see if that shows anything. The site (sadly) worked great for me on all security settings.

Comment: Perhaps you can ask one of the affected users, whether they can access your API URL directly in their IE, by typing it into the address bar. That could give an indication as to whether the address maybe gets blocked by a firewall/content filter or something.

Comment: Also, I see you are sending the request header `Authorization: MYAUTHTOKEN123` – now usually an `Authorization` header value contains the authentication _method_ used first, something like `Authorization: Basic …` or `Authorization: Digest …` – could perhaps be that a firewall blocks this header because it does not conform to the “standard” form of such an Authorization header …?

Comment: First, have them check whether their browser is in compatibility mode. If it is, then I'd say you've found the problem. There are a several IE settings that can force sites to go into compatibility mode. I'd suggest checking those.

Comment: I will look into all suggestions here and get back to you with the results. Thank you!

Comment: @MagnusEngdal, did you ever solve this? I have a similar issue at the moment.